# Basic workings of probability theory on $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces, borel-measures

I am confused as to how exactly the underlying probablity space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$ relates to a probability measure $\mu:\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{C})\longrightarrow[0,1]$ where $\mathcal{C}:=\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ is the class of continuous functions $f:[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{C})$ is the Borel $\sigma$-field of subsets of $\mathcal{C}$.

As per the excellent question and answer here [Natural & important probability measures on $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$, in particular the Wiener measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142417/natural-important-probability-measures-on-mathcalc0-1-in-particular-th), I have a natural preference to avoid, at least initially, the stochastic process viewpoint. However in case this is relevant to my questions, my understanding is as follows: for each $f\in\mathcal{C}$ and for fixed $t\in[0,1]$, $f_{t}(\omega):\Omega\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a random variable as $\omega$ runs through $\Omega$ if $f$ is $\mathscr{F}/\mathscr{R}$ measurable ($\mathscr{R}$ being the linear Borel sets). I think each $f$ are measurable since continuity implies measurability. On the other hand for fixed $\omega\in \Omega$, $f_{t}(\omega):[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a *path* as $t$ runs through $[0,1]$, i.e. a realisation of a real valued function on $[0,1]$. Thus using the dot notation to signify a variable, $f_{t}(\cdot)$ is a random variable at $t$ and $f_{(\cdot)}(\omega)$ is the entire path of $f$ at $\omega$. Furthermore $(f_{t}(\omega))_{\omega,t}:=(f_{t}(\omega))_{\omega\in\Omega,t\in[0,1]}$ is a stochastic process $f:\Omega\times[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

**Random elements in $\mathcal{C}$**

**I now, perhaps naively, apply my knowledge of how the basics of probability theory work for $X$ - i.e. a random variable in a standard probability set-up)**

Suppose $\tilde{F}:\Omega\longrightarrow\mathcal{C}$ is a $\mathscr{F}/\mathcal{C}$-measurable mapping between the measurbale spaces $(\Omega,\mathscr{F})$ and $(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{C}))$, i.e. for each $\omega\in\Omega$, $\tilde{F}(\omega)\mapsto \tilde{f}$ for some $\tilde{f}\in\mathcal{C}$. Then $\tilde{F}$ is a random *element* in $\mathcal{C}$ and is analagous to a $\mathscr{F}/\mathscr{R}$-measurable mapping $X(\omega)\mapsto x$ for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$ - i.e. a standard random variable. According to Billinglsey (Convergence of Probability Measures, 2nd Ed, 1999) *elements* can mean scalars, vectors, sequences as well, and I am trying to follow this general language so I understand probability theory applied to metric spaces (of which $(\mathcal{C},d_{\infty})$ where $d_{\infty}$ is the sup metric is the most general I wll probably ever have the need to consider). The open $d_{\infty}$-balls $B_{\epsilon}(f)=\{g\in\mathcal{C}:d_{\infty}(f,g)<\epsilon\}$ centred at $f$ of radius $\epsilon$ are conceptually the same as in Euclidean space: i.e. the class of $d_{\infty}$-open sets of $\mathcal{C}$ denoted $\mathcal{U}(\mathcal{C})$ satisfy each $U\in \mathcal{U}(\mathcal{C})$ being a union of open balls, and the metric space $(\mathcal{C},d_{\infty})$ is separable and complete. The Borel $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{C}$ is crucially also generated by $\mathcal{U}(\mathcal{C})$ (this is crucial in the sense that oftentimes proving a result on the generating class then extends to the entire $\sigma$-field). However here I do not need to use such properties here.

Let $\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{\mu_{\tilde{F}}:\mathcal{C}\longrightarrow[0,1]}$ $\mu_{\tilde{F}}:\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{C})\longrightarrow[0,1]$
be the probability law of $\tilde{F}$: what does this mean and how does $\mu_{\tilde{F}}$ assign probabilities to elements in $\mathcal{C}$?;

$$\mu_{\tilde{F}}(B)=\mathbb{P}\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\tilde{F}(\omega)\in B\right\}\hspace{20pt}\text{ for all }B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{C})$$

In words: $B$ is a set of continous real-valued functions on $[0,1]$ and $\tilde{F}(\omega)\in B$ means the entire path $\tilde{F}(\omega):=\tilde{f}_{(\cdot)}(\omega)$ at $\omega$ lies in $B$. The above often gets shortened to $\mu_{\tilde{F}}(B)=\mathbb{P}\{\tilde{F}\in B\}=\mathbb{P}\{\tilde{F}^{-1}(B)\}$.

**Measurable mappings and intergals of Measurable mappings of random elements in $\mathcal{C}$**

If my understanding about random elements is OK, how are measurable mappings of these random elements defined, and furthermore how are intergals of these mappings of elements defined? **Once again I now perhaps naively apply my knowledge of how this works for $X$)**. Let $\phi$ be a positive-valued $\mathcal{C}/\mathscr{R}$-measurable function (i.e. function of functions such as $\phi(\tilde{f})\mapsto\text{max}\left\{|\tilde{f}_{t}|:t\in[0,1]\right\}$). Then $\phi(\tilde{F})=\phi\circ \tilde{F}$ is a $\mathscr{F}/\mathscr{R}$-measurable mapping (theorem 13.1 (ii), Billingsley 1995, Proabability and Measure, 3rd Ed), and as far as I can tell, I am free now to apply standard measure theory pertaining to the integral of random variables to this mapping - i.e. no new theory of integration required (Billingsley 1995 uses a quite general set-up so perhaps here I am benefiting from investing in this extra generality).

Using the defintion of expectation of random variables, the change of variable theorem (lines 5 and 6), and the definition of the integral for positive mappings;

$$\begin{align*}
\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{\mathbb{E}_{\mu_{\tilde{F}}}\left[\phi(\tilde{F})\right]
}\mathbb{E}_{\mu_{\tilde{F}}}\left[\phi\right]&:=\int_{\mathcal{C}}\phi(g)\mu_{\tilde{F}}(dg)\\
&:=\text{sup}\sum_{i}\left\{\left[\underset{g\in B_{i}}{\text{inf}}\phi(g)\right]\mu_{\tilde{F}}(B_{i})\right\}\\
&=\text{sup}\sum_{i}\left\{\left[\underset{g\in B_{i}}{\text{inf}}\phi(g)\right]\mathbb{P}\left[\omega:\tilde{F}(\omega)\in B_{i}\right]\right\}\\
&=\text{sup}\sum_{i}\left\{\left[\underset{g\in B_{i}}{\text{inf}}\phi(g)\right]\mathbb{P}\left[\tilde{F}^{-1}(B_{i})\right]\right\}\\
&=\int_{\mathcal{C}}\phi(g)\mathbb{P}\circ\tilde{F}^{-1}(dg)\\
&=\int_{\Omega}\phi(\tilde{F}(\omega))\mathbb{P}(d\omega)\\
&:=\text{sup}\sum_{i}\left\{\left[\underset{\omega\in F_{i}}{\text{inf}}\phi(\tilde{F}(\omega))\right]\mathbb{P}(F_{i})\right\}\\
&:=\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}\left[\phi(\tilde{F})\right],
\end{align*}$$

where the supremums extend over all finite decompositions $\{B_{i}\}$ of $\mathcal{C}$ into $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{C})$-sets and all finite decompositions $\{F_{i}\}$ of $\Omega$ into $\mathscr{F}$-sets.

This all seems perfectly reasonable to me but please do point out where I have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mistake in your reasoning, but some notational imprecision which might be a source of confusion. Firstly:

> Let $\mu_{\tilde{F}}:\mathcal{C}\longrightarrow[0,1]$ be the probability law of $\tilde{F}$

A measure is a functional on a $\sigma$-algebra, so one should write $\mu_{\tilde{F}}:\mathcal B(\mathcal C)\longrightarrow[0,1]$.

Secondly, whereas your understanding of what the law of a random variable is is completely correct, one might want give as a definition what you derive as a conclusion. (The two points of view are obviously and immediately equivalent, but somewhat different in spirit).

Say $(S,\mathcal S)$ is a measurable space, and $X$ is an $S$-valued random variable on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr F,\mathbb P)$. (That is, in analytical terms, $X$ is an $\mathscr F/\mathcal S$-measurable function.)

> The *law* $\mu$ of $X$ is the measure $X_*\mu:= \mu \circ X^{-1}$

i.e. the *push-forward measure* of $\mu$ via $X$.

Now to the last bunch of formulas.

> $$\mathbb{E}_{\mu_{\tilde{F}}}\left[\phi(\tilde{F})\right]:=\int_{\mathcal{C}}\phi(g)\mu_{\tilde{F}}(dg)$$

The left-hand side as you write it here does not make sense. Indeed, $\mu_{\tilde{F}}$ is a measure on $\mathcal C$, whereas $\phi(\tilde{F})$ (which here should really be written $\phi\circ \tilde F$, for clarity) is a function on $\Omega$. One cannot integrate a function defined on *some* measurable space w.r.t. a measure on *another* measurable space.

I assume (from the $:=$ symbol) that what was meant is

$$\mathbb{E}_{\mu_{\tilde{F}}}\left[\phi\right]:=\int_{\mathcal{C}}\phi(g)\mu_{\tilde{F}}(dg)$$
which is the definition of expectation.
Then,
$$
\mathbb{E}_{\mu_{\tilde{F}}}\left[\phi\right]=\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}\left[\phi(\tilde{F})\right],
$$
is nothing but the standard [change of variable formula for push-forward measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure#Main_property:_change-of-variables_formula), which you basically reproved (again correctly).

Comment: Super! Thank you so much for the confirmation. Yes the two notational issues I missed - the first was in essence a typo (I simply forgot the B to denote Borel sigma field), the second was laziness (I should have picked it up when reviewing my question. Point noted about using composition of functions notation.

Comment: @dandar indeed I imagine from what you wrote that your command of the subject is quite good. I preferred to point it out because it was difficult to find the source of your confusion (if any ;) One further comment: when trying to understand something, one should not mix the analysis and the probability perspective. Both can be valuable, but when one does not understand a concept, phrasing it in two distinct languages at a time usually does not improve the situation.

Comment: totally agree that mixing languages is not helpful, the problem is I am not sure the difference  between analysis language and probability language, other than the latter uses many analysis techniques and results. I was only aware of trying to avoid stochastic processes in the question (to simplify things). If you could shed a little more light on the difference in languages that would be very useful to me.

Comment: @dandar This is topic for a wealth of new questions ;) My 2 ¢ are: only work with analysis to understand concepts, write them up in probability if the context allows. Probabilistic language is usually less technical and many details can be "hidden" without losing clarity nor correctness. In grasping things though, these details are necessary to be spelled out completely. Example: understand disintegrations of measures, use regular conditional probabilities. (Disclaimer: I know many people who would tell you the exact opposite)